# GraphQL / Relay - do all tables need to be queried in main QueryRenderer?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, react-relay

I'm new to GraphQL and Relay and I'm struggling with queries, fragments, ...spreads & passing props. I think I'm unnecessarily passing props down through many, many components. I want to learn how to teleport my data objects from the QueryRenderer to deeply nested components, skipping all the ancestor components.

Suppose I have a component structure like this. I need a list of emojis from the 'emoji' table inside `EmojisList` component which is deep in the app. I'm not sure where to spread or pass props or when to ask for the actual scalars.

```
<MainApp>
  <QueryRenderer 
    environment={environment}
    query={graphql`
        query MainAppQuery {
        currentPerson { // current user
            ...Timeline_currentPerson
        }
        allEmojis {
            ...ReactionBar_emojisList
          }
        }
    `}
  />
  <Timeline currentPerson={props.currentPerson}>
    <PostList>
      <Post>
        <ReactionBar>
          <EmojisList>
            // I need this list
            export default createFragmentContainer(ReactionBar, {
              emojisList: graphql`
                fragment ReactionBar_emojisList on EmojisConnection @relay(plural: true) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      name
                      rowId
                    }
                  }
                }
              `,
            });      
          </EmojisList>
        </ReactionBar>
      </Post>
    </PostList>
  </Timeline>
</MainApp>
```

[image: Console error]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fragment Container](https://relay.dev/docs/en/fragment-container)

Wrap `<EmojiList />` Component with `createFragmentContainer` HOC then it will grab all of the data you need that you have fetched at the root from `QueryRenderer` .

The data will be accessible as props inside the component

```
// EmojisList.js
import {createFragmentContainer, graphql} from 'react-relay';

class EmojisList extends React.Component {/* code */}

// Export a *new* React component that wraps the original `<EmojisList>`.
export default createFragmentContainer(EmojisList, {
  emojisList: graphql`
    fragment EmojisList_emojisList on EmojisConnection {
      edges {
        node {
         name
         rowId
        }
      }
    }
  `,
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I actually had it wrapped in a createFragmentContainer, but forgot to add it. (added to OP). I keep getting this error: createFragmentSpecResolver: Expected prop emojisList` to be supplied to Relay(ReactionBar), but got undefined.` The GraphiQL query for getting all emojis is allEmojis {edges { node { scalars }}}